# question about limes inferior/superior

Tags: analysis

Does $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\sup x_n \leq \lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \inf x_n$ implies

$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\sup x_n = \lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \inf x_n=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} x_n$?

Comment: See: [Limit superior and limit inferior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_superior_and_limit_inferior#Properties).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, as by definition:
$$
\inf_{k \geq n} x_k \leq x_n \leq \sup_{k \geq n} x_k
$$
and:
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \inf_{k \geq n} x_k =  \liminf_{n \to \infty} x_n \leq \limsup_{n \to \infty} x_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sup_{k \geq n}  x_k
$$
Your first inequality forces equality for the second identity, so by squeeze theorem, the sequence must converge.

Comment: This isn't quite right. This only holds if the limit of $\{x_n\}$ is already known to exist.

Comment: @UmbertoP. You're right, thanks for highlighting. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If $(x_n)$ is a bounded sequence of real numbers, both $a = \liminf x_n$ and $b = \limsup x_n$ are finite and are cluster points of $(x_n)$. Moreover, $a$ is the smallest cluster point and $b$ is the largest. If $a = b$, the sequence has a unique cluster point (and it is bounded) so it converges to this unique cluster point.